# else statements always run

Tags: python, if-statement

I am trying to build a program with python and whenever I use the `elif` statements, they never work.  Like if I put `500` in for `freq` then I get `Sorry` as the output when I should get `bad` instead.

What am I doing wrong?

```
freq = raw_input()
if freq <= "87.10" :
    print("Sorry")
elif freq <= "108.10" :
    print("bad")
else:
    print("good")
```

Comment: I feel bad for people coming from Tcl to Python... the fact that you *couldn't* do that would be mind-boggling!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are comparing stings; these are compared *lexicographically*, not as numbers. `'5'` sorts before `'8'`, regardless of what follows, just like `Alpha` is sorted before `Beta`, because `A` comes before `B`, regardless of what other characters follow.

Compare numbers instead:

```
freq = float(raw_input())
if freq <= 87.10:
    print "Sorry"
elif freq <= 108.10:
    print "bad"
else:
    print "good"
```

Note: you are using Python 2 (or `raw_input()` would not be available), so `print` is a *statement*, not a function.

Comment: Also note that in python3 this would resulted in an exception being raised.

Comment: Print as a statement: `print "hello world!"` - oops looks like you included that

Comment: @SethMMorton: Yes, a `NameError`, because `raw_input()` doesn't exist. No, this is not about numbers vs. strings, because `raw_input()` returns a string.

Comment: No, I mean comparing floats to strings... Or am I wrong?  I don't use python3 often.

Comment: @SethMMorton: **if** the OP had turned `freq` into a number, then yes, comparing strings to numbers would have raised a `TypeError`. However,  `freq` was a *string*, so the OP is comparing strings to strings.

Comment: Duh.... you're right (of course). If I go back and look at all the comments I've made on SO, I think that over 95% of my stupidest comments have been made on your posts.  I wonder why that is...  I'll try to be more observant when you answer next time!